# Chart bundle js is not showing dynamic data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chart.js, bar-chart

I am using chart bundle js.
On alter show everything is fine but on map nothing is showing.

Please fix this issue if anyone can. Thanks in advance.

```
<script>
        var url = "{{url('stock/chart')}}";
        var Month = new Array();
        var Labels = new Array();
        var Prices = new Array();
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.get(url, function (response) {
                var total=0;
                var date=0;
                response.forEach(function (data) {
                    var dateObj = new Date(data.created_at)
                    var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; 
                    var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
                    var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
                    var date=year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'get',
                        url: '{{URL::to('day/sale')}}',
                        data: 'date=' + date + '&vendor_id=' + data.vendor_id,
                        success: function (data1) {
    //when i alert data and data 1 it showing right result 
   Month.push(day + '-' + month + '-' + year);

                            Prices.push(data1.sum);
                        }
                    });
                });

                var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: {
                        labels: Month,

                        datasets: [{
                            label: 'eFreshUp',

                            /* data: Prices,*/
                            data: Prices,
                            backgroundColor: [
                                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                            ],
                            borderColor: [
                                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                            ],

                            borderWidth: 2
                        }]
                    },
                    options: {
                        scales: {
                            yAxes: [{
                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero: true
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I am using chart bundle js map. On alter show everything is fine but on map nothing is showing.
The ajax call does not seem to be working in the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data` option for your `$.ajax` call needs to be specified as name/value pairs, not as a query string. The `ajax` call converts these into the query string for you.

So

```
data: {"date" : date, "vendor_id": data.vendor_id},
```

Comment: by update 
 var  sum=0;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'get',
                        url: '{{URL::to('day/sale')}}',
                        data: {"date" : date, "vendor_id": data.vendor_id},
                        success: function (data1) {

sum=data1.sum;


                        }
                    });
                            Month.push(day + '-' + month + '-' + year);

                            Prices.push(sum);

                });

showing date on chart is correct  but sum=o